# In Ag-grid React v29+ camelcasetohumanreadable function has been removed. What's the alternative?

Tags: ag-grid

In recent releases of Ag-grid React v29+ **camelcasetohumanreadable** function has been removed.

In our existing project we are using it to convert camelcase string to Normal string.

What is the alternative of it in newer vesrions?

#ag-grid

I have upgraded to latest version of ag-grid.

Comment: function camelCaseToHumanReadable(camelCaseString) {
        const result = camelCaseString
            .replace(/([A-Z][a-z])/g, ' $1')
            .replace(/([A-Z]+)/g, ' $1')
            .replace(/ +/g, ' ')
            .replace(/^ +/g, '');
        return result.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + result.slice(1);
    }